# multi value function $F(z)=\ln(1+z-2z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

Prove that on circle $|z|<\frac{1}{2}$ we can get a branch $f$ of multi valued function $F(z)=\ln(1+z-2z^2)$

Comment: HINT: $1+z-2z^2=(1-z)(1+2z)$. Cut the plane with a straight line from one branch point to the other.  Is $f$ analytic inside $|z|=1/2?$

Answer (score 1):

This shows the branch cuts of @Mark Viola.

[image: plot]